# How do I make html5 slider (input type='range') work in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, browser, range

I try to use html5 element, which is

```
<input type='range' step='1' min='-300' max='-1' />
```

It is supposed to be a slider. It works in Chrome.  But it does not work in Firefox8.
I checked that in "html5test.com", it says firefox 8 partially supports the "range" type. It supports "min" and "max" attribute, but not "step" attribute. Then I erase the "step" attribute, like

```
<input type='range' min='-300' max='-1' />
```

Why it still does not work?

Is any way to let it work?

Comment: To see the latest browser implemation of the slider component see http://caniuse.com/input-range (Its still not supported as of FF 15 btw)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [not supported](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344618) in Firefox before version 23. For a Javascript implementation in versions 4 and up, please see http://frankyan.com/labs/html5slider/ .

According to [Jonathan Watt's comment](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344618#c55) on the bug report linked above, support has been added to the Firefox development branch and was released with version 23.

Comment: @shareef Firefox 23 is the current beta version. The bug for it if you're interested: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=344618

Comment: Firefox 23 has now been released so range is supported. See [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/User:Jonathan_Watt/range) for styling info.