# HTML5 input type range vertical in Firefox

Tags: html, slider

I use this implementation for my web app: http://frankyan.com/labs/html5slider/ 
It works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome. In Crome you just change the `-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;` for a vertical implementation but that doesn't work in Firefox. I want to use the same slider implementation but in vertical orientation? I don't want to use and Framework sliders. Please help.

Comment: According to the http://stackoverflow.com/a/8041753/328555 answer, this a known bug in Firefox. Looks like you might be stuck using the html5slider framework.

Comment: I'm finding it very hard to belive that changing the orientation is such a big problem.

Comment: Hm... I played around with it a little bit, and applying a CSS transform to rotate the slider did rotate it - see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kgLEm/ Unfortunately, I can't get the slider thumb to drag in Firefox. My guess is that the click handler code doesn't like the transformation much. You might be able to fix that in the html5slider library.

Comment: You could always use `transform: rotate(90deg);` as a workaround (with the appropriate css prefix), although it will not wrap around the other elements on the page correctly.

Comment: Using rotate visually makes the slider verticall. But the slider is still checking for horizontal movement.

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in Firefox before version 23.

So I'd recommend you to use Jquery :

```
 $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
      orientation: "vertical"
});
```

Quite easy and fast !

have a look here for a further info :

http://jqueryui.com/slider/#slider-vertical