# Alternative HTML/CSS for Firefox not supporting input range

Tags: javascript, html, firefox

In my web application I'm using an input type range element.

```
<div id="fontSlide">
    <input type="range"
           id="rangeBar"
           min="0"
           max="2"
           value="0"
           onchange="EM.adjustFontSize(this.value)"
           title="Scrolla per cambiare la dimensione del testo">
</div>
```

Unluckily, it is not supported by [Firefox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox) and Internet Explorer before version 10.

I could create an alternative HTML for Internet Explorer using conditional comments, but how can I handle it with Firefox? Can I specify somehow at least a different CSS (hiding it could be OK)?

I prefer not to use `Jquery.browser` because I know it is deprecated, and also to import something like `modernizer.js` just for one check is too heavy. The best solution would be one single JavaScript check line, something really light.

CSS hacks are my last recourse. I used it and made it work weeks ago, but then I updated my Firefox version and now it is not working anymore. This made me realize that CSS hacks are too risky.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041641/how-do-i-make-html5-slider-input-type-range-work-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

Use [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI), more specifically *[Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range-vertical)*. It will save a lot of time.

Comment: I cannot use jquery to change the main html, i just can modify it to not have a range element in case of firefox browser, this is a costrain