# input type="range" control is not working in firefox browser

Tags: html, forms, firefox, htmlcontrols

This Control isn't working in Firefox, please someone could help me?

```
  <input type="range" name="points" min="1" max="10">
```

Comment: your title and question, both expels different meaning.

Comment: Which version of Firefox and which OS? I am on Linux, Firefox 23 and it works fine.

Comment: FireFox 8 and windows 7 OS

Comment: This input don't work in your firefox version, you'll need firefox 23 at least.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make html5 slider (input type='range') work in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041641/how-do-i-make-html5-slider-input-type-range-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041641/how-do-i-make-html5-slider-input-type-range-work-in-firefox) stackoverflow post.

> This is not supported in Firefox before version 23. For a Javascript implementation in versions 4  and up, please see http://frankyan.com/labs/html5slider/ .

Comment: Then input type number contral also is not working in firefox

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not supported in firefox before version `23`:

http://caniuse.com/input-range

May be you're still using old version of firefox. Try to upgrade it to the latest version or at least version `23` which is support this feature.